# UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct C.Friends memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity

I'm always getting this error:
UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct C.Friends memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
I don't know what is wrong and how to fix it.
Can someone help me, please?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract C {
    
    struct Friends{
        string name;
    }
    
    struct Person{
        string name;
        Friends[] friends;
    }
    
    mapping(string => Person) persons;
    
    
    
    function map(string memory name)public{
        
        
        Person memory person;
        persons[name] = person;
    }
     
}
```

Comment: From your code, it seems that all you need is `persons[name].name = name`.

Comment: nope, does not work

Comment: ass soon as I try to add the friends array the error occurs

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract C {
    struct Friends {
        string name;
    }
    
    struct Person {
        string name;
        Friends[] friends;
    }
    
    mapping(string => Person) persons;
    
    function map(string memory _name, string[] memory _friends_names) public {
        persons[_name].name = _name;
        
        uint256 length = _friends_names.length;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
            persons[_name].friends.push(Friends(_friends_names[i]));
        }
    }
    
    function returnSingleStruct(string memory _name) public view returns(string memory, string[] memory) {
        uint256 length = persons[_name].friends.length;
        string[] memory friends_names = new string[](length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
            friends_names[i] = persons[_name].friends[i].name;
        }
        
        return (persons[_name].name, friends_names);
    }
}
```

In my example you can insert array of `Friends` structs for struct `Person`. I also built getter method which is returning the name of the person including array of the friends.

Comment: So do you indirectly create a struct through  persons[_name].name = _name; ?

Comment: Yes. BTW in my example you can see I'm saving _name for struct Person with mapping key _name which is a bit useless, because you're saving _name twice ( you don't have to save the name inside the Person struct, you already did that when you used the name for unique mapping key ). I left it like on purpose for the test, you can save whatever information you want in the struct ```Person```.